# Is it possible to pass a variable out of a pdb session into the original interactive session?

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

I am using pdb to examine a script having called `run -d` in an ipython session. 
It would be useful to be able to plot some of the variables but I need them in the main ipython environment in order to do that.

So what I am looking for is some way to make a variable available back in the main interactive session after I quit pdb. If you set a variable in the topmost frame it does seem to be there in the ipython session, but this doesn't work for any frames further down.

Something like `export` in the following:

```
ipdb> myvar = [1,2,3]
ipdb> p myvar
[1, 2, 3]
ipdb> export myvar
ipdb> q

In [66]: myvar
Out[66]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per ipython's [docs](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/Documentation), and also a `run?` command from the ipython prompt,

> after execution, the IPython
>   interactive namespace gets
>       updated with all variables defined in the program (except for `__name__`
>       and sys.argv)

By "defined in the program" (a slightly sloppy use of terms), it doesn't mean "anywhere within any nested functions found there" -- it means "in the `globals()` of the script/module you're `run`ning.  If you're within any kind of nesting, `globals()['myvar'] = [1,2,3]` should still work fine, just like your hoped-for `export` would if it existed.

**Edit**: If you're in a different module, you need to set the name in the globals of your original one -- after an `import sys` if needed, `sys.modules["originalmodule"].myvar = [1, 2, 3]` will do what you desire.

Comment: I had tried making the variable a global but this doesn't seem to work if another module has been called in one of the frames.
 
For example if you run test.py which calls a function in test2.py and then declare a global in this frame I can't see it in either the higher up frames (executing in another module) or the ipython namespace afterwards.

Comment: If you're in a different module, you need to set the name in the globals of your original one -- editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: Turns out that making a variable global in a frame inside a module called from the original script puts it only in the __dict__ of that module. So from the top-most frame "test2" is in globals() and "myvar" is in globals()["test2"].__dict__. 

I think I presumed that making the variable global would put it straight into globals() for the top frame (and ipython) but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Started my last comment before yours had come up. 
Marking as accepted. Thanks for the help!