# How to export a variable from PDB?

Tags: python, pdb

Imagine the following scenario: a script is started from the IPython shell and at a break point the python debugger is called. Using the PDB commands one can analyze the code and variables at this point. But often it turns out that the values of the variables call for a deeper research.

Is it possible to export the value of a variable to the IPython shell?

My specific use case:
I struggle with a quite huge numpy array which does not seem to have the correct values. I know that I can run any python commands from the python debugger, but it would be helpful to save the values of the variable at different break points and to use all of them at IPython shell. I am imaging something like

```
ipdb> global var1; var1 = var
ipdb> continue
...
ipdb> global var2; var2 = var
ipdb> continue
... 
In [2]: abs(var1 - var2) # do some interesting calculations with IPython
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass a variable out of a pdb session into the original interactive session?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114080/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-variable-out-of-a-pdb-session-into-the-original-interac)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use globals():

```
ipdb>__name__
'my_module'
ipdb> get_var = 'a value'
ipdb> globals()['myvar'] = get_var
ipdb> q
In [11]: my_module.myvar
Out[11]: 'a value'
```

This assumes the break point is set in `my_module.py`, so we are editing the globals of the module `my_module`.

Comment: This does not work, but I'm not sure why. I get `'myz' is not defined`.

Comment: @lumbric how do you running it?

Comment: I think it did not work, because `myvar` most likely lives in a different module than, not directly in IPython. I edited your answer to clarify. Please check if that is correct!

Comment: Instead of using globals(), you can just import any module, and assign the variable to a field in that module. This was more straightforward for me.

Comment: `import sys`, then `sys.modules['__main__'].myvar = get_var`

Answer (score 7):

Not a pretty solution, but working:

```
ipdb> import cPickle; f=open('/tmp/dump1','w+'); cPickle.dump(var,f); f.close()
```

...

```
ipdb> import cPickle; f=open('/tmp/dump2','w+'); cPickle.dump(var,f); f.close()
```

then

```
In [2]: var1 = cPickle.load(open('/tmp/dump1'))
In [3]: var2 = cPickle.load(open('/tmp/dump2'))
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to distinguish different `globals()`.
For example, suppose we have a module: mymodule.py

```
foo = 100
def test():
    bar = 200
    return bar
```

We run it under the control of `pdb`.

```
>>> import pdb
>>> import mymodule
>>> foobar = 300
>>> pdb.run('mymodule.test()')
> <string>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) print foobar
300
(Pdb) print foo
*** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
(Pdb) global foobar2; foobar2 = 301
(Pdb) print foobar2
301
```

At the beginning, namely, before executing `test()`, the environment in pdb is your current `globals()`. Thus `foobar` is defined, while `foo` is not defined.
Then we execute `test()` and stop at the end of `bar = 200`

```
-> bar = 200
(Pdb) print bar
200
(Pdb) print foo
100
(Pdb) print foobar
*** NameError: name 'foobar' is not defined
(Pdb) global foo2; foo2 = 101
(Pdb) print foo2
101
(Pdb) c
>>>
```

The environment in pdb has been changed. It uses `mymodule`'s `globals()` in `test()`. Thus 'foobar`is not defined. while`foo` is defined.

We have exported two variables `foobar2` and `foo2`. But they live in different scopes.

```
>>> foobar2
301
>>> mymodule.foobar2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    mymodule.foobar2
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'foobar2'
>>> mymodule.foo2
101
>>> foo2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    foo2
NameError: name 'foo2' is not defined
```

You have already found the solution. But it works slightly differently.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers and comments above, this felt the most straightforward approach for me:

```
ipdb> import sys
ipdb> sys.abcdef = some_debugged_variable
ipdb> c

In [18]: import sys
In [19]: ipython_var = sys.abcdef
```

You can also store a dict there and hold multiple named objects if need to do so.