# Spyder debugging: Storing run-time variables in the workspace?

Tags: spyder

When I am running python code in Spyder using the debugger, is there a way to store run-time variables from a particular function call in the workspace so that they can be accessed from the console after the run is complete?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this other question:

[How to export a variable from PDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859282/how-to-export-a-variable-from-pdb)

**Note**: I'm just leaving this as an answer not to claim that I solved the problem myself but just for future reference, i.e. in case someone else looks for this question but related to Spyder (and he/she doesn't know the technical terms: pdb, globals, etc).